# GET parameter in URL adding If...THEN

Tags: php, parameters

I'm totally new to PHP, and have no idea how to get this simple function straight. I want to retrieve the parameter from the url, testsite.com?name=chris, and then use the parameter to drive an IF...THEN statement,

```
if ($_GET['name'] = "chris") {
    echo "Have a good day! ". $_GET['name'];
} else {
    echo "Have a good night unknown!";
}
```

I just get Have a good day! Chris no matter what I do, even if I change the name parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You wrong to use simbol :

```
if ($_GET['name'] == "chris") {
    echo "Have a good day! ". $_GET['name'];
} else {
    echo "Have a good night unknown!";
}

$x=1;  //$x is 1 
$x=='1' // is if $x is equal to 1
```